# Interpolate a high frequency time series

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation, forecast

I have a physical time series in a range of 2 year sample data with a frequency of 30 minutes, but there are multiple and wide lost data intervals as you can see there:

[image]

I tried with the function `na.interp` from `forecast` package with a bad result (shown above):

```
sapply(dataframeTS[2:10], na.interp)
```

Im looking for a more useful method.

UPDATE:

Here is more info about the pattern I want to capture, concretely the row `data`. This subsample belongs to May.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the underlying pattern has lots of variation in it. Are you looking for an interpolation that "looks real"? Seems a little like the "Enhance!" function on TV shows. Perhaps you could do some sort of FFT filter to pick out major frequencies of the signal and add those to a linear interpolation?

Comment: Interesting, coud you provide a source/example for this approach?. (Note I update with more info about the underlying pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try the `**imputeTS**` package. It's an R package dedicated to time series missing value imputation.

The `na_seadec()`, `na_seasplit()`, `na_kalman()` methods might be interesting here

There are many more algorithm options - you can find a list in this [Paper](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-009/RJ-2017-009.pdf) about the package.

In this specific case I would try:

```
na_seasplit(yourData)
```

or

```
na_kalman(yourData)
```

or

```
na_seadec(yourData)
```

Be aware, that it might be you need to give the seasonality information correctly with the time series. (you have to create a time series (`ts` object) and set the `frequency` parameter)

Still might be that it won't work out at all, you will have to try.
(if you can provide the data I'll also give it a try)